# Adding DefaultPrice from InventoryItem to Kit Specification

Tags: acumatica

I need to add a Default Price field value for a particular StockItem (IN202500) on Price/Cost Info tab on Stock Components tab grid in Kit Specifications (IN209500).

I have declared an unbound field as below and populating it in FieldSelecting Event. However for some reason custom column is not getting populating.

```html
public abstract class usrBasePrice : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
[PXDecimal(4)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Price", Enabled = false)]
public virtual decimal? UsrBasePrice { get; set; }

protected void INKitSpecStkDet_UsrBasePrice_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
 INKitSpecMaint invKit = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INKitSpecMaint>();

 INKitSpecStkDet row = e.Row as INKitSpecStkDet;
 if (row != null)
 {
  InventoryItem item = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(invKit, row.CompInventoryID);

  if (item != null)
  {
   INKitSpecStkDetExtension ext = PXCache<INKitSpecStkDet>.GetExtension<INKitSpecStkDetExtension>(row);
   ext.UsrBasePrice = item.BasePrice;
  }
 }
}
```

Any suggestions if I am missing anything.

Comment: I figured out, there is nothing wrong with the code. It was cache issue. I have cleared the cache and the value populated.

Comment: Instead of using this, 
INKitSpecStkDetExtension ext = PXCache<INKitSpecStkDet>.GetExtension<INKitSpecStkDetExtension>(row);
   ext.UsrBasePrice = item.BasePrice;
you can write like this --  e.ReturnValue = item.BasePrice.

Comment: I agree, thanks John